# unable to get weekends from my calendar script

Tags: javascript, calendar

i tryed so many things. Nothing will working or i get the wrong weekends.

My Calendar looks like:
Jan 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 etc
Feb 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc

i have to colering the weekends. But i have a problem to check if its saturday or and sunday. get only the wrong days

function getmonthname is an array for monthnames.

```
<script>
var Year = 2017;

function getDays(m,y){
    return new Date(y,m,1,-1).getDate();
}

var myDate = new Date();

//monate erstellen
for( var i=1; i <=12; i++){

    $("#kalbody").append('<div id="kalenderLine' + i + '" class="kalenderLine"></div>');
    $("#kalenderLine"+i).append('<div id="month'+i+'" class="monthName">'+getMonthname(i)+'</div>');


    //tage für monate erstellen
    for( var mi=1; mi <=getDays(i,Year); mi++){             


    //weekends

myDate.setFullYear(2017);
myDate.setMonth(i);
myDate.setDate(mi);

if(myDate.getDay() == 6 || myDate.getDay() == 0) {

    wE="weekend"
    console.log(mi+'.'+i);

}
else{
    wE="";  
}

        //wE="";
        $("#kalenderLine"+i).append('<div class="dayCell '+wE+'"> <span class="dayCellNr">'+mi+'</span> </div>');
    }
}
</script>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: create date with necessary date values and check if `[0,6].indexOf(date.getDay()) > -1`